# Is there a log viewer application that can read log messages from Azure Table Storage?

Tags: enterprise-library, azure-table-storage, etw, logging-application-block, etw-eventsource

Microsoft recently released [Enterprise Library 6](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn169621.aspx) which contains the new [Semantic Logging Block](http://entlib.codeplex.com/releases/view/101823). One of the options available with the Semantic Logging Block is the ability to write log messages to [Windows Azure Table Storage](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/table-services/), which sounds like a great way to implement logging in my Azure-based applications. Unfortunately, I'm not sure what to do with the logs once they are there--are there any log viewers that can retrieve log entries from Azure Table Storage? I guess I'm basically looking for a "tail" utility that monitors Azure Table Storage rather than a file.

Comment: This is a great question. I just use Visual Studio's Server Explorer or ClumsyLeaf's TableXplorer, but they don't have any "ETW knowledge", they just display the rows which is too simplistic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Cerebrata tools](http://www.cerebrata.com/products/overview) for viewing and managing the data.